# No module named Crypto import error for sage

Tags: python, sage

I'm running Sage's notebook on an Ubuntu machine and I'm using module crypto for using AES. My code is `from Crypto.Cipher import AES`. There are lots of posts with the error `ImportError: No module named Crypto` but none of them works for me apparently because I have a python anaconda installation and a python installation for Sage. How can I solve it?

Comment: pip intall pycrypto?

Comment: I tried that, everything is ok for anaconda but still sage does not work.

Comment: are you sure you're running correct python then? do which python and verify that it's the one installed by anaconda

Comment: What version of Sage are you using? How did you install it? Please provide the full error message you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing the pycrypto module with Sage's pip,
by running the following in a terminal:

```
$ sage --pip install pycrypto
```

Then start Sage and use the Crypto module:

```
$ sage -q
sage: from Crypto.Cipher import AES
sage:
```