# In Sage: No module named 'Crypto' --> ssl errors with pip

Tags: ssl, pip, pycrypto, sage

I see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787908/no-module-named-crypto-import-error-for-sage) that the solution is to run:

```
sage --pip install pycrypto
```

Yet, when I try this, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pycrypto/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pycrypto/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pycrypto/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pycrypto/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pycrypto/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pycrypto/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pycrypto/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycrypto (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycrypto
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: Operating system? Version of Sage? How was Sage installed?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Mac. SageMath version 9.2, Release Date: 2020-10-24. Not sure how it was installed. Is there a way to check?

Comment: It could have been built from source, or installed via Conda, or as a mac app. Try running `ls -halF $(which sage)` and `sage -c "print(SAGE_ROOT)"` to help figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have Sage 9.2, I would suggest upgrading.

The best way to do so depends on

- whether you intend to develop Sage or only use it
- what extra packages you need to install with Sage

If you

- only intend to use Sage
- only need pip-installable packages

then consider installing the latest Sage-macOS from

- https://github.com/3-manifolds/Sage_macOS/releases

Then launch Sage and, at the Sage prompt, run

```py
%pip install pycrypto
```

and similarly for any pip-installable packages you need.

Then quit Sage and launch it again.